# No matching bean of type [org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social

I'm using Spring Social to connect to Twitter.
The connect part works okay, but when I try to get the friends list, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

My Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/social")
public class SocialController {

    private final Twitter twitter;

    @Inject
    public SocialController(Twitter twitter) {
        this.twitter = twitter;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/twitter/friends", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String friends(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("profiles", twitter.friendOperations().getFriends());
    return "twitter/friends";
}
}
```

My XML config is as follows: (only relevant part shown)

```
<!-- Spring Social -->
    <bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
        <property name="connectionFactories">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="${twitter.consumerKey}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${twitter.consumerSecret}" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                    <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
        factory-method="noOpText" />

    <bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
        class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="jpaDataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository"
        factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
        <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
        <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
        <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Spring Social -->
```

Please guide. I'll be very thankful.

### EDIT

I think I forgot to add

```
@Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public Twitter twitter() {
        Connection<Twitter> twitter = connectionRepository().findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        return twitter != null ? twitter.getApi() : new TwitterTemplate();
    }
```

to the XML file. Any idea how it would be represented in the XML context. I'm new to Annotation based config & hence using xml based ones. Please help.

### EDIT 2

I settled for a workaround. Decided to use both Annotation based config and XML based config together.
Just adding the thing I did for everyone:

I added a config:

```
public class SocialApiConfig {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        Connection<Facebook> facebook = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
        return facebook != null ? facebook.getApi() : new FacebookTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public Twitter twitter(ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        Connection<Twitter> twitter = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        return twitter != null ? twitter.getApi() : new TwitterTemplate();
    }
}
```

Then included this in my XML based config

```
<bean class="com.joinups.config.SocialApiConfig" />
```

Thanks to everyone for guiding me get the correct answer! Thanks a lot. You guys rock!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you did not declare a bean of type `Twitter`.

from the [spring documentation](http://www.springframework.net/social-twitter/refdoc/api.html#twitter-getProfile) I can see you need to instanciate the `Twitter` in some way.

Try declaring a bean `<bean id="twitter" factory-bean="twitterConnectionFactory" />` with the correct parameters required to instanciate the `TwitterTemplate` object

#### edit:

here is the configuration via xml:

```
<bean id="twitter" factory-method="ﬁndPrimaryConnection"
    factory-bean="connectionRepository" scope="request" depends-on="connectionRepository">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter" />
</bean>
```

see [this ohter - possible dupe - question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687871/how-to-configure-spring-social-via-xml)

Comment: You're correct, but I'm struggling with converting @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
    public Twitter twitter() {
        Connection<Twitter> twitter = connectionRepository().findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        return twitter != null ? twitter.getApi() : new TwitterTemplate();
    } to XML. Can you guide.

Comment: That's awesome. I did a workaround. See edit in the question footer. But I will still accept this as an alternative answer. Infact actual answer to my question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - ConnectionRepository#findPrimaryConnection returns a Connection<Twitter>, which isn't the same as a Twitter object.  Creating an intermediate factory bean which calls Connection<Twitter>#getApi causes the error in the linked dupe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687871/how-to-configure-spring-social-via-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Please look through the beans in the context in a debugger and look to see if there is a class derived from org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter there. I doubt there is. I've not used the Twitter API, but I expect there is a XML configuration element to tell Spring to use it or there is a Twitter API jar that needs to be on your classpath somewhere.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Chris. That's definitely the mistake. I've missed to add the config (now edited the question, please check EDIT footer). Can you guide how do I add it in the application-context.xml? I'm new to annotation based config.

Comment: just a thought. Try removing the @Scope annotation to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Component Scan occurs before the beans in your config are loaded. At the time of Injection, Twitter does not exist. You can either define the Twitter bean in XML like PH has stated. Also try using @Autowired instead of @Inject for supplying the dependency to the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

you are using annotation based declaration for `Twitter` you probably need to add something like this in your spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

[Annotation-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)