# Are the consumer/access tokens and secrets protected via TwitterTemplate?

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am planning on a simple standalone, non-webapp Twitter demo for the purpose of getting my hands wet with spring-social; there is no frontend. For simplicity, everything will be run off method `main` for the demo and the `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, `accessToken`, and `accessTokenSecret` are all visible.

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret,
    accessToken, accessTokenSecret);
```

Does interacting with `twitter.xxOperations()` protect the underlying keys and secrets?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by this, but still try to give you an explanation of what I have learned so far.

> Does interacting with twitter.xxOperations() protect the underlying keys and secrets?

When you use `TwitterTemplate()` you are allowing everyone (every User who have access to your service) to access `xxxOperations()`, this is [Anonymous Twitter Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727911/how-to-allow-anonymous-twitter-connections-in-an-mvc-configuration/34967994#34967994).

Whereas if you use `Twitter()` constructor as demonstrated in this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/) you restrict Users and force them to login to Twitter.com to access `xxxOperations()`provided by your service.

I just pushed my experiments with Spring-Social-Twitter in my [Github](https://github.com/RawSanj/Spring-Twitter-Stream) repo, you might wanna checkout. Hope this helps.